# unacught Reference Error :Cannot access 'Mascota' before initialization. Error al recoger información de un formulario en js

Tags: javascript

```js
let prop = document.getElementById('propietario').nodeValue;
let nombreMascota = document.getElementById('nombreMascota').nodeValue;
let direccion= document.getElementById('direccion').value;
let telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
let enfermedad = document.getElementById('enfermedad').value;
let tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;

if(tipo=="perro") {
let  perro = new Mascota(prop,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(perro);
}
else if(tipo=="gato"){
    let gato = new Mascota(prop,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(gato);
}
else if(tipo=="conejo") {
    let  conejo = new Mascota(prop,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(conejo); 
}

let mostrarResult = (valor)=> {
    let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado ul')
    resultado.innerHTML=" ";
    
    let li1 = document.createElement('li');
    li1.innerHTML=`${valor.datosPropietario()}`;
    let li2 = document.createElement('li');
    li2.innerHTML = `${valor.tipo()}, mientras que el nombre de la mascota es : ${valor.nombreM()} y la enfermedad es :${valor.enfermedad()}`;
    resultado.appendChild(li1);
    resultado.appendChild(li2);
}

formulario.addEventListener('submit',mostrarResult);


class Propietario {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono){
        this.nombreP=nombreP;
        this.direccion=direccion;
        this.telefono=telefono;
    }
    datosPropietario(){
        return `El nombre del dueño es : ${this.nombreP} El domicilio es : ${this.direccion}, y el telefono de contacto : ${this.telefono}`;

    }
};

class Animal extends Propietario {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo){
        super(nombreP,direccion,telefono)
        this.tipo=tipo;
    }
    get tipo(){
        return `El tipo de animal es un : ${this._tipo}`;
    }
    };

class Mascota extends Animal {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreM,enfermedad){
        super(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo);
        this._nombreM=nombreM;
        this._enfermedad=enfermedad;
    }
    get nombreM(){
        return this._nombreM    }
    get enfermedad() {
        return this._enfermedad    }

    set nombreM(nombreM_nuevo){
        this.nombreM=nombreM_nuevo;    }

    set enfermedad(enfermedad_nuevo){
        this._enfermedad=enfermedad_nuevo;    }
        
}
```

```css
form {
    font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tajawal:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Desafio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
            <img src="./assets/img/conejo-perro-gato.jpg" alt="animales" class="img-fluid">
            <h2 class="my-3">Consulta Veterinaria</h2>
        </div>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="propietario">Dueño: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="propietario" aria-describedby="textoAyuda">
              <small id="textoAyuda" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca compartiremos tus datos.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="telefono">Numero Telefonico: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="direccion">Lugar de Residencia: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombreMascota">Nombre de la Mascota: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreMascota">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tipo">Tipo</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="tipo">
                  <option value="perro">Perro</option>
                  <option value="gato">Gato</option>
                  <option value="conejo">Conejo</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="enfermedad">Motivo de la consulta: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enfermedad">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
          </form>
          <div class="text-center mt-5">
              <p>Datos Agregados</p>
              <div id="resultado">
                  <ul></ul>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

En este formulario pretendo mostrar la información recabada del formulario en el div resultados . No obstante , al utilizar la página no hay efecto alguno y en la consola del navegador aparece un error que es unacught Reference Error :Cannot access 'Mascota' before initialization , por lo que parece que hay que inicializar primero la clase Mascota, pero ese componente del código no logro comprenderlo cabalmente. He visto otros ejemplos en internet , aunque son diferentes , ante lo que no es posible aplicarlo a este ejemplo, por tanto, quisiera saber si alguien puede darme alguna sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como las variables creadas con `var` se pueden llamar desde cualquier parte del script pero las variables creadas con `let` o `const` no, las clases tienen un comportamiento similar a estas ultimas, es decir no puedes hacerles referencia antes de ser inicializadas, este vendría ser el caso de tu problema, como solución mueve las clases a la parte de arriba del script, por ejemplo podrias ponerlas entre las lineas `let tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;` y `if(tipo=="perro") {` (en el orden que se encuentran Propietario>Animal>Mascota)

Comment: Hice la modificación y corregí algunas otras, pero sigue dando error